# How to reverse 'java.util.stack' variable content

Tags: java, collections

Variable :

```
Stack<Entity> entityStack = new Stack<Entity>();
```

It has following values :

```
sub_sub_sub1
sub_sub1
sub1
root1
```

I want these values in another stack (or list) in reverse order :

```
root1
sub1
sub_sub1
sub_sub_sub1
```

I have applied simple logic to reverse it :

```
for (int itr = entityStack.size()-1; itr >= 0; itr--) {
   entityStackTemp.push(entityStack.get(itr));
}
```

Is there any in-built method of collection to achieve this considering performance of execution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Collections.reverse(entityStack);
```

Comment: @Ted - Correct, my bad. I thought we were dealing with Sort.